# interface builder breaks on dual display

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

I frequently connect and disconnect my laptop from a secondary display. Additionally I work in a small group that uses svn to manage xib files.  It seems that if you drag a UIView display into a secondary display in interface builder and save the xib then either disconnect that display or open it on a computer with a secondary display in  a different postion (left v right of the screen for example) then the view can't be seen/closed/moved. I've found no work around other than attaching a secondary display in the same position. This can be a real pain.

Has anyone found a solution to this?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, don't move the window off the main screen.

In System Preferences -> Display there is a Button to gather all windows on the current display. This button only appears when there *is* a second display plugged in.

Also, file a bug with Apple.

Comment: the gather all windows button does not seem to work. But I kind of found a work around. If you drag the missing view into a new empty view and then remove it from the empty view it pops back into the correct screen.

Comment: if the button would work, there wouldn't be a problem in the first place. IT IS A BUG!